# I want to call java program which is text to speech convertor and I want to send text from jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets, java

***This is java text to speech file i want to call this file in jsp in pass parameter to to this file  and retrive result on jsp file***

```
public class TextSpeech 
{
     public static void main(String[] args){
        try
        {
            System.setProperty("freetts.voices",
               "com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");
            Central.registerEngineCentral
               ("com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
            Synthesizer  synthesizer =
               Central.createSynthesizer(new SynthesizerModeDesc(Locale.US));
            synthesizer.allocate();
            synthesizer.resume();
            synthesizer.speakPlainText("Can you hear me now?", null);
            synthesizer.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
            synthesizer.deallocate();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you have servlet to handle the request from jsp?

Comment: So whats the issue? Also post your application's directory structure.

Comment: You have the code for the text-to-speech thingy, so just take it from the main function there and put it in a servlet's doPost or doGet....

Comment: Do you want to generate a MP3 file? Or play the sound in the browser? Because right now, you will generate some voice on your server (somewhere in your basement), not on the client. Do you know that?

Comment: JSP only web application are still possible, but are deprecated for years. You'd better have a servlet to manage requests and simply forward to JSP for the view part. It much simpler to write and to test.